# Как получить access token к StackExchange API?

Tags: python, requests, stackexchange-api

В StackExchange API некоторые методы требуют аутентификации, например, получить мой аккаунт - `/me` (документация - https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me).

Каждому такому методу нужен `access_token`:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/me?site=stackoverflow')
>>> response.text
{
  "error_id": 401,
  "error_message": "This method requires an access_token",
  "error_name": "access_token_required"
}
```

- пишет, что "*This method requires an access_token*" - нужен access token.

Только вот вопрос: **как его получить?**

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/6629/oauth-procedure-for-standalone-user/6638#6638 - см. раздел про implicit flow (разница описана здесь: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как я очень долго разбирался с этим, приведу здесь инструкцию, может быть кому-то поможет.

1. [создайте](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) приложение:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   **Обратите внимание:**

   - в поле *OAuth Domain* нужно ввести именно `stackexchange.com`;
   - включите *Enable Client Side OAuth Flow*.
2. перейдите на страницу только что созданного приложения из [списка ваших приложений](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth) и скопируйте поле *Client Id* (ID вашего приложения):

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. перейдите по ссылке `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=<ID ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ>&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success/`, вставив скопированный ID приложения.
4. нажмите *Approve*

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. теперь адрес примет вид `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success/#access_token=<ACCESS TOKEN>&expires=86400`
6. скопируйте access token из адреса, теперь он ваш!

---

А теперь, как его использовать:

1. скопируйте ключ со страницы вашего приложения:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. в API нужно передавать и ключ, и access token, пример:

   ```py
   >>> import requests
   >>> response = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/me?site=stackoverflow&access_token=<ACCESS TOKEN>&key=<КЛЮЧ>')
   >>> response.text
   {
     "items": [
       {
         ...
         "display_name": "wchistow"  # это действительно я!
       }
     ],
     "has_more": false,
     "quota_max": 10000,
     "quota_remaining": 9999
   }
   ```

---

PS: полученный по этой инструкции токен доступа не имеет разрешения на запись, т. е. с его помощью нельзя отправлять POST-запросы (например, написать комментарий). Чтобы получить разрешение на это, нужно

1. при правке приложения в поле *Stack Apps Post* начните вводить заголовок вопроса о вашем приложении на сайте [*StackApps*](https://stackapps.com/), при вводе будут предлагаться подходящие варианты - просто щёлкните на нужном, и поле заполнится, при этом, вопрос должен иметь метки либо `app`, либо `script`. **Важно:** этот вопрос должен быть именно *вашим*, но можно создать просто что-то вроде https://stackapps.com/q/10459/116701.
2. при получении токена в адрес нужно добавить `&scope=write_access`.